# GULP work too slow - JS task

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have a problem with GULP. So project build very slow, but only JavaScript Task.

I use: plumber, jshint, concat and uglify.

GULP version: 3.9.1
Node version: 0.12.7

Time build: 7.5[s] (earlier this same project build arround 5[s] by GRUNT).

Value of src is array (a lot of JS files).

```
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
return gulp.src(jsFilesPath)
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(jshint())
    .pipe(concat("main-" +MainJsVersion+ "-min.js"))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(outputObDirJS))
```

});

So what I should do?
 - Update Node?
 - Use others task to JS?
 - Something others?

Please remove my comment what I added to this post

Comment: We can't help you if we don't know what's happening. At least post your gulpfile.

Comment: Please edit and insert your code in the question - with code formatting

Comment: Are 7½ s really that bad? Most likely to do this process once. Registering to Stackoverflow and posting this question may have cost you 5 minutes. How often do you want to redo the transformation until you break even?

Comment: It's really bad because GRUNT build this project in 5 second. What is more interesing "sass"/"css" build in 3[seconds] or less. 

So Can I improve this?

Comment: By now you'll have to run the script close to [100 times](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=7+minutes+%2F+\(\(7.5+-+3\)+seconds\)) to make the cut. You are doing something wrong if you need to run gulp that often.

Comment: Is it one tool that's slowing things down? Can you comment them out one at a time to see? Are you using gulp watch in another task? It seems odd that you would have to run this often enough for it to matter

Comment: Hi @Barryman9000  - I tried turn off all tasks and probably it's good way to fix problem. So when '.jshint' and 'uglify' was off together project builds very fast, less than 2-3 seconds. So what others modules can I use? Because I need this modules to my project 

or maybe can I use this same modules but another way to create tasks - make sense?

You asked about 'watch', so this same.